# How to join the table based on condition in join keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have Two table, and I want to join them, but the join key is depend on the condition.  For example when table2 column2 value is not represented in table1 start values, I want to join the
on the next value. For example,   table2 column2 value 9 is not in start value, and I want to merge on value 10 (next possible value) from start columns.

```
    select * from table1 left join table2 on table2.column2=table1.start or 
table2.column2=table1.start+1 or table2.column2=table1.start+2 .. until I find merge value from start columns
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `LAG` analytic function to find the previous `start` in `table1` and then join between the previous and current values:

```sql
SELECT t1.col1,
       t1."START",
       t2.*
FROM   ( SELECT t.*,
                LAG("START") OVER (ORDER BY "START") AS prev
         FROM   table1 t
       ) t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 t2
       ON ((t1.prev IS NULL OR t1.prev < t2.col2) AND t2.col2 <= t1."START")
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (col1, "START") AS
SELECT 'a', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'v', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'b', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'r', 14 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (col1, col2) AS
SELECT 'a',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'q', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 's', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', 13 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| COL1 | START | COL1 | COL2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 10 | a | 9 |
| a | 10 | q | 10 |
| v | 11 | s | 11 |
| b | 13 | d | 13 |
| r | 14 | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Sf6oRHHl)